# Как сделать тестовый конфиг, который будет перед всеми тестами загружать sql-скрипты

Tags: java, юнит-тесты

Есть основной конфиг подключения к дб и загрузки SQL-схемы.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foxminded.university")
@PropertySource("classpath:connection.properties")
public class AppConfig {

    @Value("${database.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${database.driver}")
    private String driver;
    @Value("${database.user}")
    private String user;
    @Value("${database.password}")
    private String password;
    @Value("${schema}")
    private Resource schema;

    @Bean()
    public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driver);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(user);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer() {
        ResourceDatabasePopulator populator = new ResourceDatabasePopulator();
        populator.addScript(schema);

        DataSourceInitializer dataSourceInitializer = new DataSourceInitializer();
        dataSourceInitializer.setDataSource(dataSource());
        dataSourceInitializer.setDatabasePopulator(populator);
        return dataSourceInitializer;
    }
```

}

Есть тесты

```
@SpringJUnitConfig(TestConfig.class)
@Sql({"/schema.sql", "/data.sql"})
public class JdbcClassroomDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private JdbcClassroomDao classroomDao;
}
```

Как мне сделать так, чтобы не приходилось над каждым тестом копировать @sql({"/schema.sql", "/data.sql"}), а просто определить это в тестовом конфиге.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.foxminded.university")
@Sql(scripts = {"/schema.sql", "/data.sql"})
public class TestConfig {

}
```

Важное замечание: Мне нужно это сделать без Spring boot